# How to load a BitmapImage in MetroUI Dynamically

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, bitmapimage, imagebrush

I've been experimenting with Windows 8 and Metro UI, I've written a perfectly reasonable load of a bitmap image, but it doesn't seem to be loading, any help is appreciated.

```
Public Sub New(Image As String)

Debug.Print("ms-resource://MyAssembly/" & Image)


Img = New ImageBrush()
Dim Bitmap As New BitmapImage()
Bitmap.UriSource = New Uri("ms-resource://MyAssembly/" & Image, UriKind.Absolute)

Img.ImageSource = Bitmap
Width = Bitmap.PixelWidth
Height = Bitmap.PixelHeight

Debug.Print("Height: " & Height & " Width: " & Width)

End Sub
```

In this example Width and Height always take values of zero.
It is rendered in the same class..

```
    Public Sub Render(X As Integer, Y As Integer, Canv As Canvas)

        Dim Sprite As New Shapes.Rectangle
        Sprite.Width = CDbl(Width)
        Sprite.Height = CDbl(Height)
        Sprite.Fill = Img
        Sprite.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, CDbl(Y))
        Sprite.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, CDbl(X))
        Canv.Children.Add(Sprite)

    End Sub

End Class
```

And here is where it is created/called:

```
V = New Sprite("Images/Test.bmp")
gameRoot.Children.Clear()
V.Render(100, 100, gameRoot)
```

===

it isn't a problem with my canvas object, because if i fill it with             `Sprite.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)` then it works fine, and I see a white square on my screen, the bitmap in question is set to "Copy Always", and is in the destination folder when i view it.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to figure this out myself.

You can get a base uri by using
Me.Uri; or in C# This.Uri.

Here is the finished code that will enable anyone to load a bitmap image into a canvas; and even rotate it.

I wrote this myself, so anyone who discovers it having the same problem can feel free to use it as they please.

Image must take the format "FilePath/Image.extension"

```
Public Class Sprite

    'Public Shared Baseuri As Uri

    Public Img As ImageBrush
    Public Bitmap As BitmapImage

    Public Sub New(Image As String, Base As Uri)

        'Debug.Print("BASE:" & Base.ToString)
        'Debug.Print("USING:" & Image)
        'Debug.Print("RESULT:" & New Uri(Base, Image).ToString)

        Img = New ImageBrush()
        Bitmap = New BitmapImage(New Uri(Base, Image))

    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Render(X As Integer, Y As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer, Canv As Canvas)

        Img.ImageSource = Bitmap
        Dim Sprite As New Shapes.Rectangle
        Sprite.Width = CDbl(Width)
        Sprite.Height = CDbl(Height)
        Sprite.Fill = Img
        Sprite.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, CDbl(Y))
        Sprite.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, CDbl(X))
        Canv.Children.Add(Sprite)

    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Render(X As Integer, Y As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer, Canv As Canvas, Angle As Integer)

        Img.ImageSource = Bitmap
        Dim Sprite As New Shapes.Rectangle
        Sprite.Width = CDbl(Width)
        Sprite.Height = CDbl(Height)
        Sprite.Fill = Img
        Sprite.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, CDbl(Y))
        Sprite.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, CDbl(X))

        Dim v As New Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RotateTransform
        v.Angle = CDbl(Angle)
        v.CenterX = Width / 2
        v.CenterY = Height / 2
        Sprite.RenderTransform = v


        Canv.Children.Add(Sprite)

    End Sub

End Class
```